My download speed is decreased in browsers after making changes in registry and running commands
I watched a network optimization video for Windows on the internet and did some changes on my PC according to the video. After what I did, I realized when downloading something via Brave it took longer than it was supposed to. And I checked other browsers too, and they are the same. After that, I checked my Debian VM and saw that it gets higher download speeds on the browser. I'm sharing the changes that I made in the Windows Registry and the commands that I used in CMD with you below, do you see any problem?
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\ServiceProvider]
"DnsPriority"=dword:00000006
"HostsPriority"=dword:00000005
"LocalPriority"=dword:00000004
"NetbtPriority"=dword:00000007

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\QoS]
"Do not use NLA"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"TcpWindowSize"=dword:0000ff3c
"EnableWSD"=dword:00000000
"MaxFreeTCBs"=dword:00010000
"TCPTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001e
"TcpFinWait2Delay"=dword:0000001e
"ARPCacheLife"=dword:00000708
"ArpCacheMimReferencedLife"=dword:00000e10
"ArpCacheSize"=dword:000000c8
"GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize"=dword:0003ebc0         
"Tcp1323Opts"=dword:00000000
"EnablePMTUBHDetect"=dword:00000001
"EnablePMTUDiscovery"=dword:00000000
"DisableTaskOffload"=dword:00000001

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{dae0cb53-0e59-4585-9569-3feb004dd08a}
"TcpAckFrequency"=dword:00000001
"TCPInitialRtt"=dword:00000002
"TcpMaxDataRetransmissions"=dword:00000003
"MTU"=dword:000005d4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Psched]
"NonBestEffortLimit"=dword:00000000

Command Prompt

netsh int tcp set global dca=enable

netsh int tcp set global netdma=enable

netsh int tcp set global ecncapability=disabled

netsh int tcp set supplemental custom congestionprovider=ctcp

netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled


None of those changes would explain performance changes with your internet. All those changes are fairly harmless, and fairly pointless, and the video was more or less snake oil.

Check a VM or anything where the old settings are that were fast, check what they were and revert back, then test if your internet is fast again.

These changes are not harmless at all. They disable critical features around MTU, which could severely affect achievable throughput. I suggest reverting all changes.

Did you take a backup of your registry keys before making these changes? If so, you may want to revert back to them... If you didn't, then you should have.

The main problem I see is that you did a ton of unnecessary changes acccording to a YouTube video without making a note of the original values of all those parameters.
A good rule is to never leave things changed unnecessarily – that is, when you're experimenting with such knobs, you should have a plan how to undo the changes, not only if they have a negative result, but also if they seem to have no result at all (they might have a negative result and you won't notice until you've forgotten what you changed).
Aside from that, I suspect that these options would be one of the big problems:
"TcpWindowSize"=dword:0000ff3c
"GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize"=dword:0003ebc0
"Tcp1323Opts"=dword:00000000

Setting Tcp1323Opts to zero disables (among other things) TCP window scaling and caps the 'receive window size' to only 64 kB. This defines how much data the OS can accept at once; then the sender is required to wait for ACK before it can send more – and the higher latency (ping) between you and the sender, the more time is wasted before that ACK arrives.
I can't math but Wikipedia says max throughput = RWIN / RTT is the formula. Suppose you have 40 ms "ping" to a server (RTT = 40ms) and you disable window scaling (RWIN = 64kB) – this would hard-limit your download speed to 64 kB / 40 ms ≈ 13 Mbps because the server has to wait a lot between sending you small bursts of data. Whereas letting the OS use scaling might result in (for example) (64 * 128) kB / 40 ms ≈ 1638 Mbps with a 128x scale factor, or more depending on what the OS decides.
In other words, setting Tcp1323Opts to 0 is not an optimization, it's a massive pessimization. Change it back to 2. (On the same note, I'm not sure what GlobalMaxTcpWindowSize is usually set to, but 256 kB seems awfully small, so I'd change it back to original as well.)
When researching this, I learned about the TCP Time-Sequence graph in Wireshark – it might be able to display the problem visually.

Among other things, you also reduced the MTU (maximum size of a single IP packet) from 1500 to 1492, which would indeed be somewhat of an optimization if your Internet connection was one that needed it – e.g. if it was a PPPoE connection that by its nature reduces the available MTU – as then reducing the MTU could avoid fragmentation and "MTU discovery" issues.
But if your connection is capable of a 1500 MTU then such a change is actually negative (in a minor way) – you're losing 8 bytes of 'useful' data per packet, while each packet's overhead remains the same. Not much of a loss, but certainly doesn't optimize anything either.
The ARP cache tweaking seems to be useless at best (and one of the parameters appears to have a typo in its name). Your LAN is nowhere large enough to warrant increasing the cache, nor does your computer talk to that many devices anyway – usually it has just your router in its ARP cache anyway.
